# How to return data from a method in a service and subscribe to that method

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

My question is simple. I've a service where I have added one method called `getBillingWeeks`. This method will make a call to an API (indirectly) and it should return the correct data. My problem is that I'm getting `undefined` when I subscribe to this method in my angular component. Here is the code:

I'm creating a service where I will keep some methods that can be called/shared by multiple components. Here is my code:

**common.service.ts**

```js
...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {

  billingWeeks = new Subject<FilterOption[]>();

  constructor(private _someOtherService: SomeOtherService) { }

  getBillingWeeks() {
    this._someOtherService
      .getBillingWeeksFromDatabase()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((data: BillingWeek[]) => {
        this.billingWeeks = data.map((item: BillingWeek) => {
          return new FilterOption(
            item.shortName,
            item.fullName
          );
        });
        return this.billingWeeks;
      });
  }
}
```

**my.component.ts**

```js
  constructor(
    private _commonService: CommonService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this._commonService.getBillingWeeks());
  }
```

No matter where i put return statement I'm getting `undefined`. Please correct my mistake.

Comment: Never subscribe in your service. Just return the observable and subscribe in your consumer (i.e component).

Comment: Oh. Then my entire structure is incorrect

Comment: You’re not far off. Plus, what you do now in the subscribe, you can still do in the service with a map on the observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many things wrong with that design. Here's what it should look like

**common.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CommonService {
  constructor(private _someOtherService: SomeOtherService) {}

  getBillingWeeks() {
    return this._someOtherService.getBillingWeeksFromDatabase().pipe(
      take(1),
      map((data: BillingWeek[]) =>
        data.map(
          (item: BillingWeek) => new FilterOption(item.shortName, item.fullName)
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**my.component.ts**

```js
  constructor(private _commonService: CommonService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._commonService
      .getBillingWeeks()
      .subscribe((data: FilterOption[]) => console.log(data));
  }
```